# cannot get a current page in the smart table tbody

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

My smart table look like :

```
          <table st-safe-src="input.inputBuckets" st-table="inputBuckets"
                 class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Timestamp</th>
              <th ng-repeat="row in input.inputSeriesPrinted">{{row}}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in inputBuckets track by $index">
              <td>{{row.key | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
             //current page is undefined
              <td ng-repeat="item in input.inputData" >{{item[$parent.$index] + (currentPage-1)*10]}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="10" class="text-center">
                <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

So, because I have ng-repeat inside ng-repeat and use parent index, I need a current page for a new set of items. Without that (only `item[$parent.$index]`) displays same data for each page. `currentPage`is undefined. Any suggestion how can I get currentPage inside mine tbody?

EDIT: [Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/zupa94/pen/YYoZGz?editors=1010) Here is my example of the problem with printed indexes of out ng-repeat and inner ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete as you haven't showen us your controller side. So, from what I understood is the answer below.

> CurrentPage is Undefined

You haven't defined it in your controller or your data value is undefined.

You can define the name of the index and use it, something like this.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.lines = [{
    text: 'Page 1'
  }, {
    text: 'Page 2'
  }];
  $scope.someData = [{
    text: 'Some Data 1'
  }, {
    text: 'some data 2'
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(pageIndex, line) in lines">
    <div class="preview">{{line.text}} Page Index : {{pageIndex}}</div>
    <br/>
    <div ng-repeat="(dataIndex, data) in someData">
        {{someData[pageIndex]}}
        Parent Index : {{pageIndex}}
        childIndex : {{dataIndex}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not what I need. Probably because of smart table pagination, going on page two I get same indexes from the parent (pageIndex in your case). So on page 1, I have indexes from 0-9 and same in second, third, etc. page.

Comment: @MatijaŽupančić I understood a part of it. Can you make a fiddle or something so I can understand and help you?

Comment: @MatijaŽupančić seems like according to the documentation of smarttables that you need to use a single ng-repeat as the directive controls the pagination.